# Spring core: Using interface result types for @Bean methods

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am reading throgh Spring core documentation and I am trying to understand this part:

> You can also declare your @Bean method with an interface (or base class) return type, as the following
>   example shows:

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

> However, this limits the visibility for advance type prediction to the
>   specified interface type (TransferService). Then, with the full type
>   (TransferServiceImpl) known to the container only once, the affected
>   singleton bean has been instantiated. Non-lazy singleton beans get
>   instantiated according to their declaration order, so you may see
>   different type matching results depending on when another component
>   tries to match by a non-declared type (such as @Autowired
>   TransferServiceImpl, which resolves only once the transferService bean
>   has been instantiated).

Okay, this sounds reasonable and I wanted to try it to see the difference, so I came up with this code:

```
public interface Hotel { }

public class LuxuryHotel implements Hotel {

  private String name;

  public LuxuryHotel(String name) {this.name = name;}

  public String getName() {return name;}
}

public class HotelGuest {

  @Autowired
  private LuxuryHotel hotel;

  public void info() {
    System.out.println("I live in the luxury hotel " + hotel.getName());
  }
}

@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

  @Bean
  public HotelGuest guest(Hotel hotel) {
    return new HotelGuest();
  }

  @Bean
  public Hotel blueHotel() {
    return new LuxuryHotel("Blue Hotel");
  }

  @Bean
  public LuxuryHotel redHotel() {
    return new LuxuryHotel("Red Hotel");
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext acac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);
  }
}
```

Now, based on the quote from the documentation above, I would have expected the following behavior: Spring tries to instantiante the beans in the order of declaration in the config class. So it will try to instantiate the `HotelGuest` bean first. Now it needs a dependency to be injected into the `@Autowired` field of type `LuxuryHotel` and looks for an appropriate bean. As the other two beans are not yet initialized, Spring does not know yet, that the bean `blueHotel()` is actually a `LuxuryHotel`, as its return type is only `Hotel`. And therefore - according to my expectation - it should see only one matching bean to be autowired, namely the `redHotel()`, which explicitely declares `LuxuryHotel` as its return type.

But the actual behavior is: Spring throws an error telling that there are two qualifying beans that can be injected into this field. So I would like to understand, what would be the correct way to interpret this part of the documentation and how to modify the example to actually see a different behavior between using interface return types and concrete return types?

Comment: A POJO should not be a bean. Also read about `@Qualifier`

Comment: I goes with @Jens. another aspect you might wanted to use **@Order** to achieve order based spring initialisation

Comment: The Spring initialization happens in several passes. First it solves to determine the dependency graph (and that it can satisfy dependencies), and then it instantiates the beans. At the time of the instantiation, it realizes it has multiple candidates.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I know I can use Order and Qualifier to customize Bean selection. But the actual question is, as I wrote: How to reproduce the different behavior between using interface return types and concrete return types for Bean methods, which the qouted docu is talking about? I thought the case which I implemented would be an example of what the docu is explaining (the actual bean type not being known in advance), but obviously this case does not work, so what would be an example of reproduing the difference between using interface return types and concrete return types?