# Spring boot : what local parameter can influence bean instantiation order?

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot 2.2 application that is a bit old, but overall working.

Recently, we have noticed that the application was not starting anymore in dev environment. The same code starts just fine locally.

The reason why it is not startind in dev is very clear :

> Parameter 0 of method companyServiceImpl in config.DomainConfig
> required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>
> - restTemplate: defined by method 'restTemplate' in class path resource [config/OAuth2ClientConfig.class]
> - oauth2RestTemplate: defined by method 'oauth2RestTemplate' in class path resource [config/OAuth2ClientConfig.class]

and indeed, in the code we have something wrong :

```
@Bean
protected RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuthDetails());
}

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details);
    oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();
    return oAuth2RestTemplate;
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public CompanyServiceImpl companyServiceImpl(OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate) {
    return new CompanyServiceImpl(oAuth2RestTemplate);
}
```

There's no Spring Boot profile and no `@Conditional` in the config. both in dev and locally, I am using JDK 11.

When running locally in debug, I observe it first instantiate `OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate`, passing it as a parameter to build `CompanyServiceImpl companyServiceImpl` , and then `RestTemplate restTemplate` is called.. so by the time `companyServiceImpl` is called, only one instance of `RestTemplate`/`OAuth2RestTemplate` exists, and the application starts. But I assume that when running in dev, the 2 `RestTemplate`/`OAuth2RestTemplate` instances get created **before** `CompanyServiceImpl companyServiceImpl` , causing the issue.

We've fixed it by removing `RestTemplate restTemplate()` and now the application starts in dev, but I am curious : why something that has been obviously wrong for so long was working ?

what could influence the order of beans instantiation in that case ? is it just luck ? I know we should not make assumptions on bean instantiation order but for such an error, I would assume it would have failed consistently.

EDIT : `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate` extends `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` , so depennding on how we look at it, it may be considered the "same"

Comment: If `CompanyServiceImpl` really has a dependency on`OAuth2RestTemplate` as you show, there's no way the `RestTemplate` bean could be injected into it; `RestTemplate` does not implement or extend `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

Comment: I guess it's not quite that simple. Possible duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59765138/639520).